# Mirth Connect get encounter details using mdth library

Tags: java, mirth

I am working on a project which will parse CCDA file and will save it into SQL DB using MIRTH connect. I have done the demographics section  and now I don't know how to get the encounter details.

I am unable to  identify the structure of encounters. The code I have written so far:

```
var doc = org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.util.CDAUtil.load(new 
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(connectorMessage.getRawData().getBytes("UTF-8")));
var Encounter = doc.getStructuredBody().get(0).getComponenets()
                   .get(4).getSection().get(0).getEncounters();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the XPath to the `encounter` node in the CCDA you're trying to get to? What do you get if you log out `Encounter.getClass().getName()` ?

Comment: How do you know that this particular MDHT module that you are using is built for that particular C-CDA that your are parsing? There are dozens of C-CDA templates, including CDA Level 1.